# jQuery clone and trigger. Bug or feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After cloning el1 to el2, it seems that el2 can not add handlers to custom trigger events. I don't know is ot a bug or feature...

**Update**: sorry me noob, mistake original.trigger() ==> $(this).trigger()

```
var original = $('div.test').find('.p1');

original.on('click', function(){
    console.log('click handler');
    original.trigger('custom');
});

original.on('custom', function(){
    console.log('custom handler 1');
});

original.on('custom', function(){
    console.log('custom handler 2'); // ok add one more handler, no problem
});

var cloned = original.clone(true, true).text("Hello Cloned");

cloned.on('custom', function(){
    console.log('WANT IT'); // IS NOT CALLED!!!
});

$("div.test").append(cloned);
```

Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/g753kt8f/1/

Don't forget to open console.

Comment: Where you are triggering "custom" of cloned?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is noobie mistake there

Comment: @zim32 You can just delete the question yourself instead.

Comment: Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead

Answer (score 1):

It's neither a bug nor a feature; it's expected behaviour.

The reason it's happening is because the `original` variable still references the previous element, not the cloned one. If you want to trigger the function on both the original and cloned elements you should use the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event:

```
original.on('click', function() {
    console.log('click handler');
    $(this).trigger('custom');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/g753kt8f/2/)

Comment: Yes this is my bug )